# SSIS: Why when I add expression variable to Connection Manager properties I lose connection?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I have a SSIS package that needs to enumerate `Excel` files in `Sharepoint`.  When I setup the `For Each` loop container at the package level and then set up the file path in my `Excel Source` at the task level everything is fine.  When I add my expression variable to the `Excel Connection Manager` properties I lose the connection and can't view my input table anymore.  I have `"Delay Validation"` set to `true` on the `Excel Connection Manager`.

Has anybody experienced this?

EDIT:

The following are screenshots of my `ForEach Loop Container` configuration:

[image]

[image]

The following is a screenshot of where I am passing the variable.  It is in the Expression box of the Excel Connection Manager:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a default value set for the variable to point to a sample file? Even though you have set the Delay validation to be True it just means that when the package runs it would not do a validation on the connection. It does not mean that while you are working on the package it would not use the variable to translate to the connection. So you should go ahead and set the default value of your connection variable to the path of the file you are working on.

[image]

Comment: Isn't that what the file path provides in the Excel Source connection string?  Im at home so not looking at Visual Studio right now.  However there is a path textbox in properties I had tried putting the path in but doesn't register what I am entering? Is this the default value you speak of?

Comment: @JeffOrris Added screenshot to answer. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: May you provide further assistance?  I am still getting these errors.

Comment: Same error after setting the path to the excel in the variable as shown in my screenshot?

Comment: Yes same error.  Im on a newer version of SSIS than the one you posted.  I am creating the variable in the ForEach Loop Container and then passing it to the Excel Connection Manager Expressions Box.  Is this what I'm supposed to do?  Thats what I usually do and works fine but I am dealing with SharePoint for the first time now

Comment: If you try pasting the sharepoint path to the connection string attribute of the connection manager, does it still though the error?

Comment: It doesn't let met.  I put in the path and press enter and deletes automatically

Comment: These are all Excel reports in SharePoint.  Is this different than a SharePoint list?

Comment: Can you add screen shots of how your variable @User::FileName is set up and how your For Each loop is set up?

Comment: I just posted a screenshot of how the variable is setup for the Excel Connection String.  Ill post the ForEach Loop container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56144/discussion-between-tmnt2014-and-jeff-orris).

Comment: I saw that screenshot for the Excel connection string set up. I was interested in seeing how your variable is set up.

Comment: So...I got the package to behave a little better as it is looping through the directory I need.  However, it is looping the file pattern I want but is looping the same file the amount of times the pattern is in the directory.  What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: Typically, in your package you would need to move the file to an Archive directory once it is processed. Another option is to rename the file to something that does not have WIP in it- REPLACE(USER::FileName, "WIP", "PROCESSED"). Using a File system task.

Answer (score 0):

I had set the DelayValidation at the connection level, at the dataflow level, and at the for-each loop in control flow level but none were working. I had spent 3-4 hours until I found this thread and setting a default value of the variable finally worked.

So setting a default value of the connection variable does solve the problem if you have a similar issue.